# CUDA and CUDAtoolkit TensorFlow in wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 with gpu enabled

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, wsl-2, object-detection-api

are CUDA and CUDAtoolkit different?
I installed CUDA using this [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform)
I ran the sample too and it worked but to run tensorflow using gpu Do I need to install CUDAtoolkit and cudnn along with the already exisiting CUDA.

while running the trainning job I am getting this message

```
2023-01-01 00:03:41.818376: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is very particular about the requirements and configurations for GPUs.  You do need to install CUDNN and I believe CudaToolkit might be a requirement to install CUDNN.

I'd recommend following the official documentation to install tensorflow with gpu capabilities.  You can see all of that here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

You can also look into Lambda Labs which has a pretty streamlined way of installing tensroflow GPU specifically on Ubuntu and adding the requirements to your `apt` repositories for automatic updating.  https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software

Comment: On the TensorFlow site, they installed it using conda but I don't conda. can I do it with pip?

Comment: They have instructions to install miniconda below https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions  You cannot install cudnn or cudatoolkit with pip as they are not python packages.  You;re also going to need a nvidia driver installed too

Comment: ok, I will install miniconda. Also, I have installed the Nvidia driver